# are numpy functions forward compatible

Tags: python, numpy

So, I had some features implemented using `numpy 1.6` and now, I want to use a library whose dependency is `numpy version > 1.8`.. So, I want to upgrade but I am not sure whether it will break anything or not..

So, the question is, if Ii have written something using previous version of numpy and I upgrade numpy.. will my functions still work?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy versions are usually close to but not always (fully) backwards compatible.

[For example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html),

```
a = np.arange(10)
b = a[1:]
c = b[1:]
```

> In numpy 1.6, `c.base` is `b`, and `c.base.base` is `a`. In numpy 1.7, `c.base`
>   is `a`.

---

I wouldn't let that stop you from upgrading, however. Your functions have a good chance of working after the upgrade, and any change you need to make is likely to be minor.

It's best to write [unit tests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) for your functions, so it is easy to check if the desire behavior is preserved.